# Select and display relational data based on what is already selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, razor

I have a SQL Server database and ASP.NET web site on which I use Razor. I have the tables `people`, `teams`, and `link_people_teams` (consisting of 2 foreign keys: `people.people_ID` and `teams.team_ID`).

On the web page I want to display a list of all team names, and under each one display the names of people in the team. I have a Razor code block at the top of the page.

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("dbName");
    var team = "SELECT team_ID,team_name FROM teams";
    var people = "SELECT people_ID,First_Name,Last_Name FROM people";
}
```

I know I need to declare more variables, but I don't know where to go from here.

On the page where I want to show the list of teams and people in the team, I only know how to generate a list of teams:

```
@foreach (var row in db.Query(team))
    {
      <p>@row.team_name</p>
      <!-- Person(s) on the team should appear next -->
      <p>Person Name</p>
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should expand your queries at the top to include joins on the foreign keys, and query for the data you are looking for.

As of right now you have two completely disconnected lists.

Make a query for peopleInTeams.

[Using Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I had an inner join set up, but did not know how to complete it.  `var peopleInTeam = "SELECT * FROM People INNER JOIN link_people_teams ON people.people_id = link_people_teams.people_id WHERE link_people_teams.team_id = ???`  Do I need another variable here?

Comment: I do not know, simply because I do not know the actual data in your database. However, for the *, you might want to instead add the actual column names.